# Equality with absolute value

Tags: python, sympy, absolute-value

Solving the equality with absolute value I use `sympy` with `nonlinsolve` function.

For example, I solve `|a + b| = a + b` as follows

```
from sympy import nonlinsolve, symbols, Abs

a,b = symbols('a, b', real = True)
eqn = [Abs(a + b) - (a + b)]
nonlinsolve(eqn, [a, b])
```

Output is OK:

`{(Interval(-b, oo), b)}`

However when I try to solve `|a - b| = -(a + b)` as below:

```
from sympy import nonlinsolve, symbols, Abs
a,b = symbols('a, b', real = True)
eqn = [Abs(a - b) + (a + b)]
res = nonlinsolve(eqn, [a, b])
```

Output is:

`False`

However clearly there exists at least one solution like `a = b = 0`.

## Update

It seems that the different behaviour in different version.
In [Python 2.7](https://live.sympy.org/) the result is
[image: formula]

But in [Python 3](https://www.sympy.org/en/shell.html) it is `False`.

Could you advise the reason of such a behaviour and possible countermeasures, since I'd prefer to use Python 3?

Comment: Where does `Abs()` come from ?

Comment: It is sympy.functions.elementary.complexes.Abs. Added to import. Thx.

Comment: The second snippet produces `FiniteSet((FiniteSet(Interval(b, oo)), Complement(FiniteSet(b), FiniteSet(0))))` for me using Sympy 1.5.1, but  `EmptySet` when using Sympy 1.10.1.

Comment: @Brian, Thanks, I used Python in R through reticulate + Rmarkdown. Seems some interferience. Got the same result in Python IDE as you. Checking.

Comment: Seems different behaviours in Python 2 and Python 3. (correct behaviour in Python 2).